# Issue with array of an object

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am learning java and was trying some stuff. This is what I am trying to do.

I am trying to create an  table of an array of an object.
e.g. I am creating an object called animal by which i can add any number of animal and its breed on user choice.

```
package tt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class animal {

    String aname;
    String abreed;

    public animal() {

        mainprog aa = new mainprog();

        System.out.printf("eneter name of your %s..\n", aa.Animalcat);
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        aname = name.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("eneter breed of your %s..\n", aa.Animalcat);
        Scanner breed = new Scanner(System.in);
        abreed = breed.nextLine();

    }

    public String getbreed() {
        return abreed;

    }

    public String getname() {
        return aname;
    }
}
```

So the main program ask for how many animals I want to add.

```
package tt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainprog {

    public static String Animalcat;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("How many animals you want to add..");

        Scanner an = new Scanner(System.in);

        int animalNumbers = an.nextInt();

        animal[][] addAnimal = new animal[animalNumbers][1];
        animaltype[] at = new animaltype[animalNumbers];

        for (int i = 0; i < animalNumbers; i++) {

            at[i] = new animaltype();
            Animalcat = at[i].getAnimalType();

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {

                addAnimal[i][j] = new animal();
            }
        }

        Display(addAnimal, at);

    }

    public static void Display(animal x[][], animaltype y[]) {
        System.out.println("Your animals are..");
        for (int m = 0; m < x.length; m++) {
            System.out.printf("Following are the name and the breed of %s ",
                    y[m].getAnimalType());
            System.out.println();
            for (int n = 0; n < x[m].length; n++) {

                System.out.printf(" %s", x[m][n].aname);
                System.out.printf(" %s", x[m][n].abreed);
                System.out.println();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
package tt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class animaltype {
    String animalType;

    public animaltype() {
        System.out.println("What kind of animal you want to add..");
        Scanner at = new Scanner(System.in);
        animalType = at.nextLine();
    }

    public String getAnimalType(){
        return animalType;
    }

}
```

The issue I have here is I can ask for how many types of animals I want to add but I can't control how many animals of that type I want to add.
While adding animal I can only add 1 number of animal manually by declaring it as [1] and can't by user input.

```
addAnimal = new animal[animalNumbers][1];
```

The problem in if I can do that by declaring `animal[][] addAnimal = null;` and then later initialize it with like:

```
animal[][] addAnimal = new animal[animalNumbers][animaltypenumbers];
```

But I get `NullPointerException` all time. Is there anyway I can have this done?

Comment: What is value of animaltypenumbers? From where will the value come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an array, it will be filled by the default value of the element it contains. Since `Animal` is an `Object`, then it will be filled by `null` values, and you cannot use any variable which has `null` value. Since you're just filling `animal[i][0]` in your current code, you won't get any problem. But it will appear when you try to access to `animal[i][1]`. This happens in `Display` method:

```
public static void Display(animal x[][], animaltype y[]) {
    System.out.println("Your animals are..");
    for (int m = 0; m < x.length; m++) {
        System.out.printf("Following are the name and the breed of %s ",
                y[m].getAnimalType());
        System.out.println();
        for (int n = 0; n < x[m].length; n++) {
            //you only filled elements in x[m][0]
            //x[m][n] when n > 0 is null
            //so you will get NullPointerException
            System.out.printf(" %s", x[m][n].aname);
            System.out.printf(" %s", x[m][n].abreed);
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

A better option:

Use `Animal[] addAnimal` instead, you don't need it to have it as an array of arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many animals you want to add..");
    Scanner an = new Scanner(System.in);
    int animalNumbers = an.nextInt();
    animal[] addAnimal = new animal[animalNumbers];
    animaltype[] at = new animaltype[animalNumbers];
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNumbers; i++) {
        //at[i] = new animaltype();
        //Animalcat = at[i].getAnimalType();
        Animalcat = new animaltype();
        //for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        //    addAnimal[i][j] = new animal();
        //}
        addAnimal[i] = Animalcat;
    }
    Display(addAnimal, at);
}
//modify Display method accordingly
```

A better option:

Use `List<Animal>` backed by `ArrayList<Animal>` instead of `Animal[]`. `List` let's you handle a list of elements that grows dynamically.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many animals you want to add..");
    Scanner an = new Scanner(System.in);
    int animalNumbers = an.nextInt();
    List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animalNumbers; i++) {
        Animalcat = new animaltype();
        animals.add(Animalcat);
    }
    Display(animals);
}
//modify Display method accordingly
```

Comment: THank you very much for the information.
But i would need array of an array cause my object would be like
addAnimal = { { dogs }, { cat}, { lions },{ tigers } };
i think i would definitely need array of an array

Comment: @user3109806 to post code in comments, enclose it using ` character: `like this`.

Comment: @user3109806 what an odd design. Anyway, if that's how you prefer it, then roll it on!

Comment: I suck at java..
I am taking video tutorials on youtube.
Am i doing right thing to learn java?
Tell me best way to start learning java, may be you can point me to some good books..